# Show only some posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How I can show only 2 posts on my websites first page?
I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@posts = Post.limit(2)
```

more info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)